# An algorithm of tree's depth works as a function definition, but not as a method definition

Tags: python, oop, recursion, tree, depth

I've writen an algorithm to recursively get a tree's depth. As a function definition, it works:

```
def tree_depth_f(tree):
    """Counts the maximum depth of a tree."""        
    def recursive_count(node):
        """Recursive count function."""
        childs = tree[node]
        if childs == None:
            return 0
        else:
            maxh = 0
            for i in xrange(len(childs)):
                h = recursive_count(childs[i])
                if maxh < h:
                    maxh = h                
            return int(1 + maxh)

    root = tree['root']
    depth = recursive_count(root)
    return depth
```

But the same algorithm as a method definition doesn't work:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        pass

    def tree_depth(self, tree):
        """Counts the maximum depth of a tree."""        
        def recursive_count(node):
            """Recursive count function."""
            self.childs = tree[node]
            if self.childs == None:
                return 0
            else:
                self.maxh = 0
                for i in xrange(len(self.childs)):
                    self.h = recursive_count(self.childs[i])
                    if self.maxh < self.h:
                        self.maxh = self.h                
                return int(1 + self.maxh)

        self.root = tree['root']
        self.depth = recursive_count(self.root)
        return self.depth
```

The `tree` is a dictionary of lists. This is how I'm testing these codes:

```
tree = {0: [1], 1: [2], 2: [3, 4], 3: None, 4: None, 'root': 0}
m = MyClass()
print "As a function:", tree_depth_f(tree)
print "As a method:", m.tree_depth(tree)
```

Here is graphical representation of the `tree` in this example:

[image]

The function definition is working fine, but when I use the method definition, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
    at Answer.py. in recursive_count on line 102
    at Answer.py. in recursive_count on line 102
    at Answer.py. in recursive_count on line 102
    at Answer.py. in tree_depth on line 108
    at Answer.py. in <module> on line 157
```

Lines 102, 108 and 157 in the original code point to these:

```
102: self.h = recursive_count(self.childs[i])
108: self.depth = recursive_count(self.root)
157: print "As a method:", m.tree_depth(tree)
```

After a lot of debug, I discovered that when the method definition finds a leaf (a node whose `self.childs` is `None`) and starts to go back from recursion, `self.childs` of the parental node is `None` too. I have no idea why. The function definition is working fine. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: @Amadan I mistyped it here, but in the original code it was correct. This is not the problem. Also, if I had forgotten the brackets in the original code, the error message would be completly different.

Comment: Yes. But it makes us debug the wrong problem. Why not make sure the code is executable before you put it in question?

Comment: It is now, sorry. The problem is in the recursion. When `self.childs` of a child node is `None`, it becomes `None` in the parental node too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying `self.childs`, which here effectively acts as a global variable (as it is recorded on the object, which persists through different calls to the recursed function). You don't have one object per node, you have one object, period. So there is no "`self.childs` of the parental node", you only have one `self.childs`, on one `self`. When a recursion exits from the `return 0` branch, the variable `self.childs` is `None`.

In your function code, your `childs` is a local variable, so each function invocation gets a separate copy; you really need this, whether on a method or on a function.

Just delete `self.`, there is no need for `childs` to be an instance variable. Indeed, there is no need for any of the variables to be instance variables, as you are not using any Object-Oriented functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your answer was very informative. After removing `self.` of all variables of this method, it started working. I'm still learning OOP. Could you please answer me one more thing? I thought when I didn't put `self.`on a variable, it automatically became a class variable that would keep its value through all instances. Is that right?

Comment: No. `self.x` is an instance variable, and belongs to the object. `x` is a local variable, and belongs to the current scope (normally, the current invocation of the enclosing function). `MyClass.x` is a class variable.

Comment: Ohhh, that really clears things up to me. Thank you!